# Защитить javascript от копирования

Tags: javascript

Приветствую всех еще раз за сегодня

Есть JavaScript, который работает. Если страницу из интернета скопировать - тоже работает. Можете дать пару советов, что прописать в скрипте, что бы копирование было как минимум затрудненно? Понятное дело умельцы - найдут способ, но от совсем примитивного копирования можно как то защититься?

p.s. конечно гугл в помощь, но там в основном описываются примеры использования их в ворд-прессе или как делать не надо.

Comment: Если хотите защититься от копирования пишите на C/C++ :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам поможет [обфускация](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Вот [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112530/) на эту тему на хабре. [Вот еще](https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80&aq=0&oq=javascript+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62l2.7769&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) по этому поводу можно почитать. А вообще я мало понимаю смысл в защите javascript-а от копирования.

Comment: То что мне нужно! Спасибо. Против копипастеров самое то.

Comment: @frank, у Вас там какой-то уникальный алгоритм, который никто еще не придумал? Гораздо разумнее лицензировать програмный код, как это делают все создатели библиотек и фреймворков. Для примера ExtJS ничего не обфусцирует, однако это не мешает им продавать свой продукт, причем не за малые деньги.

Comment: ну, я понимаю, что если я скажу что написал мега вещь - мне скажут, да ладно врать... если б знал JS на таком уровне сам бы знал как защититься. Во первых истина выяснятся в дискуссии, не кроме своих методов еще интересно чужие послушать, во вторых действительно написал кое, что серьезное.

Answer (score 11):

Можно и без обфускации, если *особенности восприятия кода* использовать:

1. Любой недокументированный код труден для восприятия.
2. Чем больше кода, тем сложнее понять, как оно работает (поэтому в ряде случаев легче переписать, чем разобраться в том, что есть).

Посмотрите, сколько js-скриптов использует vc.com - их же дикое количество. Копировать себе в проект все подряд?

Обратите внимание на коды в вопросах (до тех пор, пока те не поправит @Iranda): это же лютый ад, как правило: имена переменных и функций типа *var1* и *func2*, весь код в одну линию, комментариев нет.

*История в тему.*

> В конце XIX века свои суда Япония заказывала в Европе. Однако не все
>   заключаемые японцами договора заканчивались оформлением заказа. Часто
>   они тщательно изучали всю техническую документацию, а потом под
>   каким-нибудь предлогом отказывались от корабля.
>
> Однажды ведущий инженер английской судоверфи, будучи в кругосветном путешествии, увидел в австралийском порту японский
>   корабль, который он лично проектировал и от приобретения которого
>   японцы неожиданно отказались. Инженер догадался, что прижимистые
>   азиаты просто копировали чертежи и по ним делали суда сами.
>
> Когда на эту судоверфь вновь прибыл японский представитель, ему не стали выражать претензий, а предложили подробную техническую
>   документацию. Сценарий последующих событий повторился: через некоторое
>   время, тщательно изучив чертежи, японцы аннулировали заказ. А через
>   год в Йокогаме состоялся торжественный спуск на воду нового судна -
>   точной копии английского корабля. Однако торжества были недолгими:
>   украденные чертежи оказались с изъяном, ибо через несколько секунд
>   после спуска судно перевернулось и затонуло (Ю. Щербатых, «Искусство
>   обмана»).

Comment: Замечательная история, спасибо!

Comment: На форуме фокспро ксть раздел курилка, там обсуждения не по программированию, нот если бы на хэшкоде такое было, эта история была бы в первой. История класс. К сожалению японцы которые копируют у меня, еще немного до думывают

Answer (score 6):

- Если вас устроит вариант с `security through obscurity`, то можете воспользоваться любой из утилит, предложенных ниже:

> - **http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor/**
> - **https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2**
> - **https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/**

- Понятно, что защититься от копирования / реверсинга `Javascript'a` в общем случае нельзя, поэтому, если у вас вообще **возникла мысль** защищать что-то от копирования, то стоит подумать над переносом части логики на `server-side.`

Comment: Ответ шикарен, но соседний ответ, хоть и по хуже но в более простом виде работает. Жаль не могу 2 акцепта влепить